# What is the purpose of masking the LFSR value in STM32's noise generation?

Tags: noise, stm32, dac, random-number, random

I read on [section 14.3.8 of the STM32F4 reference manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf) that you can mask the LFSR output value partially or totally.

At first I thought that it was used to change the pseudo random pattern ([representative polynomial function](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4400)) but I'm not really sure anymore.

What's the real purpose of this mask?

I'm not very familiar with LFSR noise generation so I might have got everything wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to section 14.5.1 of that same document the `MAMPx[3:0]` bits are used to control the amplitude of the generated noise (or triangle) waveform. For noise, they simply mask off (force to zero) the high-order bits of the LFSR output.

It seems pretty clear that the noise/triangle waveform can be used as a "dithering" signal for ADC operations, and that's what they have in mind with this feature.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I still don't understand how masking the high order bits changes this amplitude of the noise waveform though... I thought it would only change the frequency response of the noise

Comment: If you mask off the high-order 8 bits from a 12-bit number, you get values in the range of 0-15 only. If you only mask off 6 bits, you get values in the range of 0-63. Bigger numbers means higher amplitude. The masking actually has no effect on the frequency content -- white noise is white noise regardless of the number of bits of resolution.

Comment: Oh yeah sure I'm sorry, I didn't think about it like that